# angular index.html script shown

Tags: html, node.js, angular, git, npm

I have deployed an Angular app in server previously with no problems until now. Angular version is 6.1.1, Angular CLI version is 6.2.9, npm version is 6.13.4 and node version is 10.18.0 in both local and server. Server is Ubuntu 20.04.

Basically, I work with the code in local (Windows), test it on localhost, push the code to git, pull from git to server, and deploy it in server.

Like usual I made some changes in components, services, and server side code, (I have not touched index.html at all) and I checked that it works fine in localhost. But, this time when I deploy, the site literally shows index.html script like so.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
...
```

I searched on StackOverflow, and someone mentioned that base href should match any other base url in the code, so I made sure that it all matched just in case.

On the server, when I deploy, I use the code 'npm run start:prod' and 'start:prod' runs the following code:

```
npm install && npm run clean:dist && ng build --aot --prod && tsc -p ./server && nohup node bin/www &
```

This code is created by former co-worker, and ever since then, I used this code without any problems.

Just to check, I reverted back to the commit that worked in server, deployed it, and it works fine. Then, I pulled the recent commit again, and I noticed a warning that says

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: package-lock.json. Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.

I git stashed it because I thought package-lock.json that worked in localhost should work in server as well, but is this where the problem lies? Or could it be something else?

Comment: Just double check  <base href="/"> is included in any of ur app.html. https://angular.io/guide/deployment for more details

Comment: @RED.Skull Thanks for the quick response. By app.html, you mean index.html plus *.component.html?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may be going through what I went through,

my problem was in express.ts.

I added the following code to fix cors issue, but it somehow threw off the index.html.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

   next();
});
```

After I commented these lines, index.html worked as it's supposed to in server.

If anyone is struggling with this kind of issue, please consider other possibilities than "base href", like my case.